# GPU programming in Standard C++

Tags: c++, gpu

I know that you can program an OS by putting your code in the first 512 bytes of the RAM and things like that, but how do you program a GPU? Is it possible in standard C++?

I've heard of CUDA, but I would like to go by standards. Does Adobe Photoshop also use CUDA?

Comment: What do you mean with GPU? the driver?

Comment: The Graphics processing unit

Comment: yeah but what do you mean with programming it? the programming it self ands in assembler anyway. So running an application on it? Or really controlling the logical units on it?0o

Comment: I don't think you can do this in pure standard C++ only, unless you actually do it by programming your own OS first. You have to go through the OS to reach the GPU.

Answer (score 4):

[CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compute_Unified_Device_Architecture) is a proprietary Nvidia language and software. It won't work on AMD graphics cards, or on recent Intel or AMD processors having an integrated GPU.

[OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) is an industry standard, available on Nvidia and AMD graphics cards (and recent processors with integrated GPU).

However, pure standard C++ don't give you access to graphics cards or GPGPUs. You'll need an operating system and some libraries.

Notice that the small codes (called kernels) running on the GPU are not coded in fully standard C++, but in a small C-like dialect (also called OpenCL). There are some limitations (no recursive function, no function pointers, etc...) because of the weird nature of GPGPUs. The programming model is not as general as in C++.

There is also [OpenACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC), a set of pragmas for C++ compilers.

Answer (score 4):

For all intents and purposes, there is no way to program a GPU without making use of some libraries, whether OpenCL, CUDA, or otherwise. While it is technically *possible* to drive the GPU directly (given that the GPU drivers are doing so!), documentation on how GPUs work is very difficult to come by, especially regarding advanced features such as those required for computation, and it's almost certainly not something you want to get involved with.

Answer (score 2):

CUDA is the standard for NVidia cards. Alternatively OpenCL is also an option for a bit more cross platform.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL

Coding a GPU is fundamentally different to coding a CPU in that you have hundreds to well in the thousands of concurrent threads hence the different way of calling functions/kernels on the GPU.

NOTE: There is no way you can run your own code on the GPU without compiling it for the GPU therefore a standard C++ compiler will only be able to call functions in libraries.

Comment: CUDA is standard? meaning I don't have to do any installations for it? it is available in C++ by itself?

Comment: If anything, OpenCL is the standard. CUDA is vendor-specific (to nVidia).

Comment: Changed it to say that it's standard for NVidia.

Comment: But openCL is authored by apple. i guess the OP means something that is built into C(++) so that you dont need anything extra. By the way, if anybody could answer this question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526977/org-alternative-for-c

Comment: YES!! exactly what @AnshumanDwibhashi said.!

Comment: @user2595281 then the answer is no. The C++ standard has no notion of a specific CPU or GPU model, nor does it have any notion of specific implementations like FPUs co-processors or multiple cores (that doesn't mean that a standard compliant compiler can't use multiple cores or the GPU to accelerate your program, it just means that the standard doesn't provide an explicit mechanism to do so). If you want to use these things explicitly then you need to use a library or OS API to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It is surely possible up do everything in C++, but you will need to use some external libraries.

You might want to consider OpenCL instead of CUDA.
CUDA is a proprietary NVidia technology, while OpenCL works on more hardware and platforms.