# ORG alternative for C++

Tags: c++, memory, assembly, operating-system, ram

In assembly we use the `org` instruction to set the location counter to a specific location in the memory. This is particularly helpful in making Operating Systems. Here's an example boot loader (From wikibooks):

```
 org 7C00h

         jmp short Start ;Jump over the data (the 'short' keyword makes the jmp instruction smaller)

 Msg:    db "Hello World! "
 EndMsg:

 Start:  mov bx, 000Fh   ;Page 0, colour attribute 15 (white) for the int 10 calls below
         mov cx, 1       ;We will want to write 1 character
         xor dx, dx      ;Start at top left corner
         mov ds, dx      ;Ensure ds = 0 (to let us load the message)
         cld             ;Ensure direction flag is cleared (for LODSB)

 Print:  mov si, Msg     ;Loads the address of the first byte of the message, 7C02h in this case

                         ;PC BIOS Interrupt 10 Subfunction 2 - Set cursor position
                         ;AH = 2
 Char:   mov ah, 2       ;BH = page, DH = row, DL = column
         int 10h
         lodsb           ;Load a byte of the message into AL.
                         ;Remember that DS is 0 and SI holds the
                         ;offset of one of the bytes of the message.

                         ;PC BIOS Interrupt 10 Subfunction 9 - Write character and colour
                         ;AH = 9
         mov ah, 9       ;BH = page, AL = character, BL = attribute, CX = character count
         int 10h

         inc dl          ;Advance cursor

         cmp dl, 80      ;Wrap around edge of screen if necessary
         jne Skip
         xor dl, dl
         inc dh

         cmp dh, 25      ;Wrap around bottom of screen if necessary
         jne Skip
         xor dh, dh

 Skip:   cmp si, EndMsg  ;If we're not at end of message,
         jne Char        ;continue loading characters
         jmp Print       ;otherwise restart from the beginning of the message


 times 0200h - 2 - ($ - $$)  db 0    ;Zerofill up to 510 bytes

         dw 0AA55h       ;Boot Sector signature

 ;OPTIONAL:
 ;To zerofill up to the size of a standard 1.44MB, 3.5" floppy disk
 ;times 1474560 - ($ - $$) db 0
```

Is it possible accomplish the task with C++? Is there any command, function etc. like `org` where i can change the location of the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible to do in any C compiler that I know of. You can however create your own [linker script](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html#Scripts) that places the code/data/bss segments at specific addresses.

Comment: So you mean, i HAVE to use Assembly for Boot loaders and it is impossible to use any other language?

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi No, you can still use the linker script to set the addresses. However, for a first-step boot-loader it's often easier to write that in assembler which then calls the appropriate higher-level code.

Comment: okay, thankyou @JoachimPileborg but can you please give some example code?

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi Not for a first-level boot-loader in C. I have never made one in C, nor have I ever seen one, but it should most definitely be possible.

Comment: no... @JoachinPileborg i didn't mean an example of a bootloader, i mean example of shifting memory with the method you prescribed

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi Ah, then just search for it. There are many examples all over the web. Especially on OS tutorial sites like [OSDEV.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) or [osdever.net](http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/).

Comment: Oh, thanks for that link osdev.org !! does it teach me to develop OS in C from scratch ?

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi osdev.org is very good, and yes it have many tutorials on how to create beginning operating systems in many languages (including C and C++) from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity, the `org` directive does not load the code at the specified address, it merely informs the assembler that the code will be loaded at that address. The code shown appears to be for Nasm (or similar) - in AT&T syntax, the `.org` directive does something different: it pads the code to that address - similar to the `times` line in the Nasm code.. Nasm can do this because in `-f bin` mode, it "acts as it's own linker".

The important thing for the code to know is the address where `Msg` can be found. The `jmp`s and `jne`s (and `call` and `ret` which your example doesn't have, but a compiler may generate) are relative addressing mode. We code `jmp target` but the bytes that are actually emitted say `jmp distance_to_target` (plus or minus) so the address doesn't matter.

Gas doesn't do this, it emits a linkable object file. To use ld without a linker script the command line looks something like:

`ld -o boot.bin boot.o -oformat binary -T text=0x7C00`

(don't quote me on that exact syntax but "something like that")  If you can get a linkable object file from your (16-bit capable!) C++ compiler, you might be able to do the same.

In the case of a bootsector, the code is loaded by the BIOS (or fake BIOS) at 0x7C00 - one of the few things we can assume about the bootsector. The sane thing for a bootsector to do is not fiddle-faddle around printing a message, but to load something else. You'll need to know how to find the something else on the disk and where you want to load it to (perhaps where your C++ compiler wants to put it by default) - and `jmp` there. This `jmp` will want to be a `far jmp`, which does need to know the address.

I'm guessing it's going to be some butt-ugly C++!